# How to change the solid color of a ripple effect

Tags: java, android, user-interface, rippledrawable, gradientdrawable

I have a toggle button with 3 custom states :
- Pressed
- Checked
- Realeased

I'm using the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/togglebutton_color_custom_ripple" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/togglebutton_color_custom_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/togglebutton_color_custom_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

I'd like to change the background color for each state of this button programmatically. I tried to use the following code:

```
        StateListDrawable drawable = (StateListDrawable) mToggleButtonCustom.getBackground();
        DrawableContainer.DrawableContainerState dcs = (DrawableContainer.DrawableContainerState) drawable.getConstantState();
        Drawable[] drawableItems = dcs.getChildren();

        GradientDrawable gradientDrawablePressed = (GradientDrawable) drawableItems[0];
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawableChecked = (GradientDrawable) drawableItems[1];
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawableUnChecked = (GradientDrawable) drawableItems[2];

        gradientDrawablePressed.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        gradientDrawableChecked.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        gradientDrawableUnChecked.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```

It works fine for 'checked' and 'released' state because I use classic shapes in XML but it doesn't work for 'pressed' state because I use the following Ripple effect in my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/ripple">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/togglebutton_size"
                android:width="@dimen/togglebutton_size" />
            <solid android:color="@color/blue_vs"/>
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/togglebutton_button_stroke"
                android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

It'd seem I have to use 'RippleDrawable' in my code but I don't really understand how, I juste want to change the solid background color, not the ripple color or stroke.

Thanks

Comment: can you post a screen of the toggle with 3 states?

Comment: I posted it, it's the first XML. I added this XML to android:background="@drawable/togglebutton_state" of my button